# Count the occurence of an element in the group without summarizing

Tags: r, data.table, counting, resampling, summarize

I have dataset that looks like this:

`x <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4), cl=c("a","b","c","b","b","a","a","b","c","a"))`

I am trying to find the probability of a row getting picked for each group (id) based on the elements in cl.

I tried the following:

`x[,num:=.N, keyby=.(id,cl)]`

`x[,den:=.N, keyby=.(id)]`

`x[,prob:=num/den, ]`

Is there a better way to do this?

Ultimately, my end goal was to use the probability values as weights while sampling a row per group (id). Any better alternatives to arrive at these weights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you meant something like this?

```
> x[, prob := prop.table(table(cl))[cl], id][]
    id cl      prob
 1:  1  a 0.3333333
 2:  1  b 0.3333333
 3:  1  c 0.3333333
 4:  2  b 1.0000000
 5:  2  b 1.0000000
 6:  3  a 1.0000000
 7:  4  a 0.5000000
 8:  4  b 0.2500000
 9:  4  c 0.2500000
10:  4  a 0.5000000
```

or

```
> unique(x[, prob := prop.table(table(cl))[cl], id][])
   id cl      prob
1:  1  a 0.3333333
2:  1  b 0.3333333
3:  1  c 0.3333333
4:  2  b 1.0000000
5:  3  a 1.0000000
6:  4  a 0.5000000
7:  4  b 0.2500000
8:  4  c 0.2500000
```

---

Explanation: `table` + `prop.table` gives the frequencies table of all elements, which are named values, and thus we use `[cl]` to subset the frequencies.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for. I didn't know the use of those functions. It would be great if you add some description

Comment: @K_D Yes, I have added some comments to my code.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to generate random samples based on the observed frequencies:

```
x[, .N , by= .(id, cl)][, prop := N/sum(N), by = .(id)][]
#    id cl N      prop
# 1:  1  a 1 0.3333333
# 2:  1  b 1 0.3333333
# 3:  1  c 1 0.3333333
# 4:  2  b 2 1.0000000
# 5:  3  a 1 1.0000000
# 6:  4  a 2 0.5000000
# 7:  4  b 1 0.2500000
# 8:  4  c 1 0.2500000
```